# ImageView source scaling done right. How?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, imageview

### Scope

Image bitmap have to be shown as imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) and scaled to fit UI. This could be done via:

1. `bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);`
2. xml's ImageView attributes such as

   ```
   android:layout_width="newWidth"
   android:layout_height="newHeight"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   ```

### Problem

Which way is better for performance? I prefer xml 'cause this is UI specific problem and I prefer to use xmls for UI definition. Also we set width/height values in dp, it means we have the same UI for different screens. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post discusses a very similar question in great detail:

[Android - Declarative vs Programmatic UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560950/android-declarative-vs-programmatic-ui)

I think the major takeaway is that if you look at the Android source, many of the views are pulled from a hash map based on their XML tag.  If it is good enough for Google in the core API, shouldn't it be good enough for us?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that doing this in the xml is the best way to go. Keeping all of your UI stuff in your xml helps you separate your view from the model of your data and controller. Or what ever pattern you are using.

Comment: Surely for the most stuff we do :) Yuo know, i work with guys who made  their won widnow (activity) management for their app for android and now have a progress with platform+plugins app. They are happy, the app is fast enough. But yes, xml UI is a best way as for me.