# Is it better to create a UI before or after the Android app is launched?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-imageview, android-view

In my Android app, I have to display 10 imageButton in the User Interface each time the user selects an option. My question is:

> Is it okay to create the UI while developing the app itself and add it to the layout folder or to create and add the imageviews to the View at the run time?

The main issue I am considering is performance? Which will give a better performance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560950/android-declarative-vs-programmatic-ui

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize performance, it's better to use XML and Java. If you're displaying 10 buttons wouldn't using XML be the easiest way to format them anyway?